# ASP.NET vNext class library, linq not available?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm using a linq expression in a asp.net vNext class library.  No errors are displayed in the editor, but when I attempt to build I see the following message:
`Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'IEnumerable<T>'.  'Select' not found.  Are you missing a reference to 'System.Core.dll' or a using directive for 'System.Linq'? FitLog.Domain.ASP.NET Core 5.0`

I do have the using statement for System.Linq, so I'm not sure what's going on.

**Update**

Here's my project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
  },

  "frameworks" : {
      "aspnet50" : { 
          "dependencies": {
          }
      },
      "aspnetcore50" : { 
          "dependencies": {
              "System.Runtime": "4.0.20-*"
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share your `project.json` file.

Comment: can you post your project.json ? 

I am unable to get it to work with this 

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23409"
      }
    } 
  }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the `aspnetcore50` target you need to add a dependency for `System.Linq` (you'll see it pop up in the Intellisense in the `project.json` file).

Comment: I have it included but the frameworks are different. am I doing something wrong?    "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23409",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    } 
  }

Comment: @eiu165 indeed many things have changed since 1+ years ago :)